# How to compare char with 0x85 correctly?

Tags: c++, char, hex, byte

iam programming in C++.
I have char* output from buffer from winsock recv. I have a little problem with comparing like this. I have char a.

```
if(a == 0x85)
```

doesnt work, but

```
if(a == -123)
```

the same(from debbuger) works..
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Don't use `char`.  Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` because the 8th bit may be a data bit, but signed numbers treat it as the sign bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if ( a == (char)0x85 )
```

Your code does not work since `a` will be converted to `int`, because on the right hand side of the `==` there's an expression of type `int`. If `a` is indeed `(char)0x85`, and `char` is `signed char` (which might not be the case on all platforms), then `a` is negative and hence `(int)a` is negative and therefore not equal to `0x85`.

Make the right hand side into an expression of type `char` and you'll have a happy day! ;)

Comment: I was thinking if it has somthing to do with signed/unsigned char.. But it works now! Thanks so much :)